# magento loop through all products by product ids

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, magento-1.8, php, mysql

My code is almost finished, but does not work..
The main idea is to assign one random related product to each product

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);

require_once "blabla/app/Mage.php"; // my path
umask(0);
Mage::app();




 /**
     * Get the resource model
     */
    $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');

    /**
     * Retrieve the write connection
     */
    $writeConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_write');




$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->getAllIds();

foreach ($collection as $product) {
$mainId = $product;
$relatedId = array_rand($collection);//get a random ID from collection



    $query = "INSERT into catalog_product_link SET 
    product_id = {$mainId},
    linked_product_id = {$relatedId},
    link_type_id = 1"     



    /**
     * Execute the query
     */

     $writeConnection->query($query);

}
echo "finish!!";
 ?>
```

Final script, made by AreDubya:

```
   <?php
    set_time_limit(0);

    require_once "/blablabla/app/Mage.php";//my path
    umask(0);




    Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);




    $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');

    $writeConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_write');

    $ids = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->getAllIds();
    foreach ($ids as $id) {
        $mainId = $id;
        $relatedId = $ids[array_rand($ids)];
        echo "$id - $relatedId<br/>";
        $query = "INSERT into catalog_product_link (product_id,linked_product_id,link_type_id) VALUES ($mainId, $relatedId ,1)";

        $writeConnection->query($query);
    }




    echo "done";



     ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT : My earlier answer didn't preserve existing links. They are accounted for in this version.

```
 <?php

    set_time_limit(0);

    require_once "blabla/app/Mage.php"; // my path
    Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
    ob_implicit_flush(true);
    ob_end_flush();

    $productModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
    $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->getAllIds();

foreach ($collection as $id) {
    $mainId = $id;
    $relatedId = $collection[array_rand($collection)];
    $product = $productModel->load($mainId);
    $linkCol = $product->getRelatedLinkCollection();
    $newPos = count($linkCol);

    echo "<strong>Product Id $mainId</strong><br/>";
    echo "Link Collection length = $newPos<br/>";

    $relatedArray = array();

    foreach ($linkCol as $link) {

        $id = $link->getId();
        $mainProd = $link['product_id'];
        $linkedProd = $link['linked_product_id'];
        $linkType = $link['link_type_id'];
        $linkPosition = $link['position'];
        $relatedArray[$linkedProd] = array('position' => $linkPosition);
        echo "Link ID = $id * Main = $mainProd * Linked = $linkedProd * Type = $linkType * Position = $linkPosition <br/>";

    }
    echo "Adding linked product - $relatedId * Position = $newPos<br/>";
    $relatedArray[$relatedId] = array('position' => $newPos);
    Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_link')->saveProductLinks(
        $product, $relatedArray, Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Link::LINK_TYPE_RELATED
    );
    $relatedArray = array();
}
echo "done";
```

EDIT: Direct Query

```
<?php

require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);


$resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');

$writeConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_write');

$ids = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->getAllIds();
foreach ($ids as $id) {
    $mainId = $id;
    $relatedId = $ids[array_rand($ids)];
    echo "$id - $relatedId<br/>";
    $query = "INSERT into catalog_product_link (product_id,linked_product_id,link_type_id) VALUES ($mainId, $relatedId ,1)";

    $writeConnection->query($query);
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, your method works.
Unfortunately it is extremely slow.. For my catalog it would take 16 days to finish, this is why I was advised to use mysql queries and am stuck with them

Comment: 16 days is too much. See the edit, I think it will work for you.

Comment: Your script works best! Thank you very much!